# JSoup will not fetch all items?

Tags: java, html, list, parsing, jsoup

So, I am trying to parse a simple list using JSoup. Unfortunately, the program only returns the entries up til the entries that start with N in the list. I do not know why this is the case. Here is my code:

```
    public ArrayList<String> initializeMangaNameList(){
        Document doc;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.mangahere.com/mangalist/").get();
            Elements items = doc.getElementsByClass("manga_info");
            ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(Element item: items){
                names.add(item.text());
            }
            return names;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
}
```

So why does the List not contain all the entries? Is there an error with the webpage? Or perhaps the parser? Can I use a workaround to bypass this issue? And what is causing the issue in the first place?

Comment: just tested your code with jsoup-1.6.1 and it returns 11906 results, which is correct.

Comment: JSoup 1.7.2 returns only 7031 results.

Comment: BINGO FOUND THE PROBLEM: 1.72 changelog Added a maximum body response size to Jsoup.Connection, to prevent running out of memory when trying to read
   extremely large documents. The default is 1MB.

Comment: @Skylion you should answer your question and mark it as closed. Don't just leave it in the comments. It's a very interesting case and it sure would help others.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Okay the issued was caused by a change in JSoup version 1.72 and higher. You just need to change the default settings like so:

```
public ArrayList<String> initializeMangaNameList(){
    Document doc;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.mangahere.com/mangalist/").maxBodySize(0).get();
        Elements items = doc.getElementsByClass("manga_info");
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(Element item: items){
            names.add(item.text());
        }
        return names;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
```

}

The important difference is setting the maxBodySize to 0 so that it allows files of unlimited size. More information can be found in the [documentation](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.Request.html).
That will allow you to have unlimited body size and load all the data you need to.

Comment: This should be mentioned on the main documentation of jsoup. Thanks.

Comment: You saved my day