# Jsoup exception: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=-1

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm recently struggling with this error:

```
org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=-1, URL=http://ekstraklasa.net/wisla-krakow/
```

Everything works just fine when running from Windows 8 machine, but when uploaded on Ubuntu server it just throws this exception.

I've tried to escape dashes in URL, print response body (there's none, only java.io.IOException: Invalid Http response) and so on.

It's not a problem with timeout setting.

I'm using Jsoup and simply ran out of ideas.

My code:

```
    org.jsoup.Connection con = Jsoup.connect("http://ekstraklasa.net/wisla-krakow/")
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36")
                .timeout(1 * 60 * 1000);
    Document doc = con.get();
```

Comment: Is it working with simple wget at your ubuntu OS?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. No, I'm getting "HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 No headers, assuming HTTP/0.9
Length: unspecified". Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Response 200 means it is working. there will be a index.html saved to your local disk. But Length: unspecified is suspicious. I posted an answer to teach how to download using HttpClient instead of using Jsoup Connection at this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23457942/jsoup-not-downloading-entire-page/23458591#23458591 . Maybe you want to try that.

Comment: I think there is something wrong from server response. Should tell Content-Length. Maybe that is the reason Jsoup cannot process.

Comment: But it's weird, because it works on Windows... I've downloaded this url using wget, but its contents are not what I expected...

Comment: It might be the server. Can you check the content encoding?

Comment: You might have to set a referrer for the webserver to return the correct data